# onActivityResult equivalent in Delphi XE5?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

In android/Java I would do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK); 
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

and get the result in:

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

In Delphi I have the equivalent of the first part:

```
Intent := TJIntent.Create; 
Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_PICK); 
Intent.setType(TJContactsContract_Contacts.JavaClass.CONTENT_TYPE); 
MainActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent,PICK_CONTACT);
```

But in looking under MainActivity I don't see a "onActivityResult" callback. I see one for JFragment but don't seem to be in the right spot to get it and I see no examples in the example code, online or in the source code.

Comment: I see several entries ending with `startActivityForResult` in  `Androidapi.JNI.App.pas`. I'm not familiar enough to say whether any of them work for what you need (thus the comment and not an answer). Do any help?

Comment: @Ken startActivityForResult is what you call to start the activity. And it's right there in the question. But the asker is looking for a way to implement an onActivityResult callback to receive the result.

Comment: What is MainActivity? Is it a pre-canned implementation of Activity? Does it expose events. How have the Delphi devs wrapped the native Android API? Are you expected to derive from Activity yourself? Or do they derive a class the overrides all virtual onXXX methods and surfaces events for you?

Comment: MainActivity is a function call that gets the Activity for the application.Looking at it's interface it pretty much matches (I havent looked at it against every single function) with what you would see in the PUBLIC part of Activity on looking on android docs (just realized that a few minutes ago).I am guessing you would have to add in an overloaded member and then derive the application from that but I am not yet familiar enough with how the Android part of XE does things to get that done. I am going to read some more source tmw to try and figure that out,just seemed like it should be simpler

Comment: I'd say that you need to derive your own Activity class actually.

Comment: @David: Yes, I'm aware of that fact. That's why I took the time to search the FMX and RTL\Android source files to see what was available. (And I also have looked at the source to see if there was another possible solution.) Thanks, though.

Comment: Btw, this cannot be done but I am told they are working on getting results from activities. Any event not specifically coded for by embarcadero is unavailable. So all the methods and functions are there but events aren't and that is what is frustrating so many XE5 android coders.

Comment: @Ferret - there is no such thing as an "XE5 Android Coder", only FireMonkey coders hoping to run their app on the Android version of the FireMonkey runtime.  If such developers are thinking of themselves as Android coders then they are just going to get frustrated.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you have to subclass the compiled Java class that acts as the entry point `Activity` on the Java side, where you can override `onActivityResult()`.
This is rather messy and requires de-dexing classes.dex to get the current `NativeActivity` subclass, that you must in turn subclass. You must also modify the manifest and replace the normally deployed classes.dex with a new one that has your subclass in it.
You may sense that this is rather messy, which is why it may be best to hold off until they add in a hook to get activity results, which should be coming along soon, hopefully...

Comment: Any tutorials or examples of doing this out there?

Comment: There's an app that uses it on my hard drive just now, which isn't strictly a helpful contribution.
However it's not yet fit for public consumption, primarily because the custom build process introduces, for no discernible reason, large amounts of FAIL on rotation. It's really quite irritating and I have yet to chase it down.
I'm hoping to have it nailed ready for my CodeRage 8 talk, but that's dependent on my working out the problem.

Comment: Actually it turns out the rotation issue was unrelated - that's caused by something else in the app.

There'll be an example of implementing onActivityResult in my CodeRage 8 session on 17th Oct '13. That's the best I can offer just now.

Comment: I ended up writing this up some long time after the mentioned talk. You can find the lengthy steps to do this in Delphi XE5 at http://blong.com/Articles/DelphiXE5AndroidActivityResult/ActivityResult.htm and the considerably simpler equivalent in Delphi XE6 at http://blong.com/Articles/DelphiXE6AndroidActivityResult/ActivityResult.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is a good review, I do not know if it work the same like Intent.

http://www.pclviewer.com/android/androidJNI.html

http://www.pclviewer.com/android/XE5.pdf

Comment: This explores how to make use of additional compiled Java code, which isn't already available in Android. So it explains how to import additional Java libraries. It doesn't really further the search for responding to launched Intent/activity results.